# Can a Tornado RequestHandler attend requests, while waiting for a Future to finish?

Tags: tornado, nonblocking, coroutine, requesthandler, concurrent.futures

Can a single Tornado `RequestHandler` class attend new requests, while waiting for a `Future` to finish in one of its instances?

I was debugging a Tornado coroutine that called a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and I noticed that, while the coroutine was waiting for the executor to finish, the `RequestHandler` was blocked. So any new requests to this handler where waiting for the coroutine to finish.

Here is the code I wrote to reproduce my observation:

```py
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop, PeriodicCallback
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
from tornado.gen import coroutine

class Handler1(RequestHandler):
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        print('Setting up executor ...')
        thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)

        print('Yielding ...')
        yield thread_pool.submit(sleep, 30)

        self.write('Ready!')
        print('Finished!')

app = Application([('/1$', Handler1)])
app.listen(8888)
PeriodicCallback(lambda: print('##'), 10000).start()
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Now, if I access `localhost:8888/1` twice I get the following output:

```
##
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
##
##
##
Finished!
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
##
##
##
Finished!
##
```

But I would expect the following to occur:

```
##
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
##
##
##
Finished!
Finished!
##
```

Notice that only the `RequestHandler` seems to be blocked, because we still get the `##` every 10 seconds. In fact if you add another identical `RequestHandler` (Handler2) and you access `localhost:8888/1` and `localhost:8888/2`, this will produce the expected output.

Is this normal? Is this the intended behaviour?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tornado creates a *new* instance of your RequestHandler for each new request. So your code indeed behaves as you expect. I run it and open two terminal windows, each running `wget localhost:8888/1`. Your code prints:

```
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
##
##
##
Finished!
Finished!
```

As you expect. What you probably see is that your browser is unwilling to open two connections to the same URL at once. Indeed, I can reproduce the "blocking" behavior you see with chrome, if I open two tabs and try to load "localhost:8888/1" in both. However, if I modify your code:

```
app = Application([
    ('/1$', Handler1),
    ('/2$', Handler1)])
```

And open "localhost:8888/1" and "localhost:8888/2" in two tabs in Chrome, I see that it opens both connections concurrently.

Try wget to test without interference from the browser.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was starting to think i was crazy. Now it all makes sense! I wasn't aware of this feature in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Also works for me:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/1 &
[1] 95055
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/1 &
[2] 95056
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/1 &
[3] 95057
```

Tornado program output:

```
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py 
##
##
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
Setting up executor ...
Yielding ...
##
##
##
Finished!
Finished!
Finished!
##
##
##
```